# DotNetNuke EventLog table is deleting

Tags: dotnetnuke

New to DotNetNuke (ver 05.06.02 (144)) and writing a SSRS report to track how many times users have logged into the system, since that is part of their job requirements.
It appears this data is stored in EventLog.LogTypeKey --> "LOGIN_SUCCESS" being the item I need to count.
The problem is that the table is getting purged somehow.  I have no hits on any successful logins that are older than roughly 24 hours.
Does anyone know the setting that is purging these values?

Thank you

Comment: It appears that it may be some kind of scheduled event because it is saving exactly 10 records per event type.  But the records do not go away immediately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the EVENT VIEWER page and go to the actions menu for the module, you can go to specific events and see what the default number of historical items to store is configured to.

EX: the LOGIN_SUCCESS event I believe stores 10 records, after that entries are trimmed from the database.

Each event type can be configured separately.

Comment: Yes just found that out on Friday.  Thanks for the verification!

Answer (score 0):

By default, DotNetNuke does not purge the EventLog table. You can find DNN's scheduled tasks in the Host menu's Schedule page. DNN schedule can execute any code that inherits the `SchedulerClient` base class provided by the DotNetNuke framework. But there is no EventLog purge code shipped as a scheduler client.

It is possible that the site administrator has added EventLog purging. Have you checked if there are any SQL Server Jobs, or Windows scheduled tasks? There is also a [Scheduled SQL Jobs](http://www.iowacomputergurus.com/free-products/dotnetnuke-modules/scheduled-sql-jobs.aspx) module to schedule sql scripts.